# DLV interactive mode (debugging)

Tags: debugging, datalog, answer-set-programming

I have been working on DLV for a little while and when the program is big I find it difficult to follow the activation of rules. So I went to the [manual](http://www.dlvsystem.com/html/DLV_User_Manual.html#SYNOPSIS) and checked if there was something to allow me to do this.

The only thing I found was the front-end option -FP but I am not sure whether this is what I am looking for since the manual does not provide enough information in this respect. So, what I did what to run my program with this flag but I get the following error:

> Background knowledge must not contain aggregates

The program runs without this flag and I cannot get rid of the aggregates. I also tried with a silly program but a different warning/error is prompted:

> Warning: No plan length given. Plan length defaults to zero.
>   No goal query has been specified.

Is this the right way of debugging DLV programs? Is there a way at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the right way of debugging DLV programs.

The planning front-end (invoked by -FP) is meant to use DLV in order to solve planning problems, i.e. problems of the general kind: 
This is the current state of the world/my system. Here is a set of possible actions I am able to perform, and here is a set of goals I want to reach. 
Now I would like to know in which order do I have to perform which of these actions to reach these goals?
(I do not know a good source for more information on planning, I had a course on that several years back during my studies - just as the result of a 50 second Google search maybe this is a useful source for more information: http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/2nd-ed/newchap11.pdf)

The planning front-end of DLV just provides you with a framework that allows you to express these kind of plans and then solves them for you (and the plan length it requests in the second Warning is the maximum number of steps a plan may take). So I do not think that this is what you are looking for.

I have no experience at all with debugging DLV, but I think it was once mentioned that the ASP IDE https://www.mat.unical.it/ricca/aspide/download supports some kind of debugging (and so it is stated on the dlv website http://www.dlvsystem.com/), but I do not know what information is provided and whether it is helpful to you. 
(In general I would assume that debugging is not so simple since the actual implementation of an ASP system may vary a great deal from the declarative definition of its semantics).

(Sorry if this is rather a comment than an answers, but I am still not allowed to write comments, only answers)